# HttpAsyncClient not getting multiple request

Tags: java, http, jsp, servlets, apache-httpclient-4.x

I my constructor of Zone's panel JFrame. i have to get zones list and operatories list from server. i am using HttpAsyncClient library to forward my request. problem is when in start i send request for my 1 list(i.e zone list) it is working but when i send request to for getting 2 lists it give's me

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"    
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.  
<init>(Lorg/apache/http/impl/nio/reactor/IOReactorConfig;)at     
org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractHttpAsyncClient.<init>
(AbstractHttpAsyncClient.java:133)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultHttpAsyncClient.<init>  
(DefaultHttpAsyncClient.java:64)
```

similirly if i send request for only(operatories list) it works fine but...it is not working when i send request for both..here is my request sender class.....
        public JSONArray sendRequest(List postPairs){

```
try {
      //At this line code gives me exception i do't know why..?
      HttpAsyncClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpAsyncClient();
      httpclient.start();
      System.out.println(postPairs.get(0).getValue());
      HttpPost post = new   HttpPost("http://10.0.0.62:8080/IDocWS/"+postPairs.get(0).getValue());
      //HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.google.com");
      Future<HttpResponse> future = httpclient.execute(post, null);
      HttpResponse resp = future.get();
      HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
      JSONArray jArray = CovnertToJson(entity);
      return jArray;
```

Comment: What version of apache http components are you using?

Comment: httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.0-beta3

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest version of HttpComponents with your project - http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi. The constructor

```
DefaultConnnectingIOReactor(IOReactorConfig)
```

does not exist in version 4.0 only 4.2+. Apache HttpClient is attempting to call this so it looks like the version of HttpClient requires version 4.2+ of HttpComponents.